# cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Not a Map or List type

Tags: junit, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, serenity-bdd

If I am using a data inside the Data Table which is not type of List or Map then it is giving me error

`cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Not a Map or List type`

This is how I am testing this. I am testing it bottom to top i.e. write function > then write step def > write feature file (just for testing purpose).

**java function:**

```
public String getScenarioName(Scenario scenario) {
        System.out.println("scenario.getName().toString());
    }
```

**step def:**

```
@And("^Get current scenario name$")
    public void get_current_scenario_name(Scenario scenario) {
        System.out.println(getScenarioName(scenario));
    }
```

**Feature file:**

```
  Scenario: Title of your scenario
    Given I have a scenario
    Then Get current scenario name
      |scenario|
```

Since I'm using `Scenario` interface as a parameter I have to use it across, in function, in steps and in feature file.

*Note: Please don't judge by the weird scenario, I am only testing it.*

I have gone through below links, but it doesn't help me. It keep giving me same error.

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/741

http://grasshopper.tech/340/ >> this one I couldn't implement, didn't quiet understand it.

Comment: @Grasshopper saw your article on converting data table. Can you please post answer pertaining to my issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking somewhat in the wrong direction. To print out the scenario name in a given step you have to capture it in a before hook before printing it in a step:

```
import cucumber.api.Scenario;
import cucumber.api.java.Before;
import cucumber.api.java.en.And;

public class ExampleSteps {

    private Scenario scenario;

    @Before
    public void capture_scenario(Scenario scenario){
        this.scenario = scenario;
    }

    @And("^get current scenario name$")
    public void get_current_scenario_name() {
        System.out.println(this.scenario.getName());
    }
}
```

Then this scenario will print `My Scenario`.

```
Scenario: My Scenario
  And I get the current scenario name
```